# how to implement the effect like the game "burn the rope"

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

which engine does this game(burn the rope) use? I want to make rope can be burn in my game. 
I have an ideas that if I dont use physic engine, I can display a rope picture, and move the fire according to the rope track(it's animation), But this is really not ideal solution.
Does anyone has any ideas? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is probably a very good idea. One improvement though, create a particle emitter for the fire, and make its velocity change direction with the accelerometer. 
Hope this helped.

Stephane